# How to improve the SelectedItem of ComboBox call in the defined class?

Tags: c#, .net

I created the defined class of `ListItem` in `WinForm` C# (.Net 6.0) and all is work on well.
But when I call the items in `SelectedItem`, need do some additional define.

```
tbCompanyValue.Text = ((ListItem)cboCompany.SelectedItem).Value;
```

Is any way which can improve like ASP.NET below call ?

```
tbCompanyValue.Text = cboCompany.SelectedItem.Value;
```

The below is my code:

```
using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;

namespace NC001
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<ListItem> li = new List<ListItem>();

            li.Add(new ListItem("CompanyA", "101"));
            li.Add(new ListItem("CompanyB", "102"));
            cboCompany.DataSource = li;
            cboCompany.DisplayMember = "Text";
            cboCompany.ValueMember = "Value";
            cboCompany.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

        private void cboCompany_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tbCompanyText.Text = ((ListItem)cboCompany.SelectedItem).Text;
            // error: object does not contain a definition for 'Value'
            // tbCompanyValue.Text = cboCompany.SelectedItem.Value;
            tbCompanyValue.Text = ((ListItem)cboCompany.SelectedItem).Value;
        }
    }

    public class ListItem
    {
        private string text = "";
        private string value = "";

        public ListItem(string text, string value)
        {
            this.text = text;
            this.value = value;
        }
        public string Text
        {
            get
            {
                return text;
            }
            set
            {
                text = value;
            }
        }

        public string Value
        {
            get
            {
                return value;
            }
            set
            {
                this.value = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use `tbCompanyValue.Text = ((ListItem)cboCompany.SelectedItem).Value;` can work well, but how to direct call `SelectedItem.value` method ?

Comment: You created a `ListItem` object, but the `ListBox` was created many years ago, and it was defined as holding `Object`s.  Thats why it tells you *object does not contain a definition for 'Value'* - it doesnt, and you cant change it.  So you have to cast the `SelectedItem` back to `ListItem` in order to access `ListItem` properties.

Comment: Nyssa, Could you can explain the detail code of cast ? I want to try it in my code.

Comment: @jack, there's nothing to explain. You're already doing the cast in the first code snippet you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no. There's nothing to be done. The `SelectedItem` property of the Web Forms `DropDownList` control is type `ListItem`, so you can use it directly as that type. In the case of the WinForms `ComboBox` control, the `SelectedItem` property is type `object`. That's because the control can contain any type of object at all. You have no choice but to cast that `object` reference as the actual type of the objects you're using in the specific case. Keep in mind that the `DropDownList` used in Web Forms is actually just a wrapper for an HTML `<select>` tag. It can't contain any custom types so having a single .NET type for the items in every control makes sense. No such logic applies to Windows Forms controls.

In order to make it work the way you want, every situation other than yours would have to become more complex. What about all the people who have bound a `DataTable` to their `ComboBox` and so their `SelectedItem` actually refers to a `DataRowView` object? What about all the other custom types that are used to populate other `ComboBoxes`?

One option is to use a custom control that perfroms the cast internally, so your usage of said control is then simplified. You could create the control like this:

```cs
internal class ComboBoxEx : ComboBox
{
    public ListItem SelectedListItem
    {
        get => (ListItem)SelectedItem;
        set => SelectedItem = value;
    }
}
```

and then use it like this:

```cs
tbCompanyValue.Text = cboCompany.SelectedListItem.Value;
```

You might also add properties to pass through the `DataSource` and `Items` if you wanted.

If you already have standard `ComboBox` contro9ls on a form, you can just edit the designer code file to change the type and you're good to go. For new instances, that custom control will be added to the Toolbox automatically, so you can add it to a form like you would any other control.

Comment: jmcilhinney, Thanks for your reply. I use defined ListItem class which because I have a system is ASP.NET. We want to try migration to Winform, so I use the same code in it. If I can use the same code which be reduce program modification.

Comment: @jack, there's nothing wrong with using your own dedicated class for the items. The point is that, no matter the type you use, the `SelectedItem` property is always type `object` so a cast is always required to use that item as that specific type. The reason you want it to be otherwise isn't really relevant to how it is.

Comment: @jack, the alternative would be to use a custom control that inherits `ComboBox` and then adds a property of the type you want. You'd still have to cast but it would be done in one place within the control instead of everywhere you want to use the property. If you're interested in that then add a comment to that effect and I'll update the answer with some code.

Comment: jmcilhinney, I have interested in inherits ComboBox way. Thanks for your help.